# Space occupied by TEXT type column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am aware of the fact that TEXT in MySQL can have maxlength of 65535 characters.

Now I create a table having one of the columns as TEXT and don't specify a length. Due to which it will take maxlength as 65535 default.

However if one of my records has a value for the TEXT column with length only as 10 characters, will the space allocated for 65535 characters be still reserved or will MySQL just use up memory required for 10 characters only?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For TEXT datatype it would be like the Actual length in bytes of string value + **(2 Bytes)**

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html) says:

> Variable-length string types are stored using a length prefix plus
>   data. The length prefix requires from one to four bytes depending on
>   the data type, and the value of the prefix is L (the byte length of
>   the string). For example, storage for a MEDIUMTEXT value requires L
>   bytes to store the value plus three bytes to store the length of the
>   value.
>
> VARCHAR, VARBINARY, and the BLOB and TEXT types are variable-length
>   types. For each, the storage requirements depend on these factors:
>
> - The actual length of the column value
> - The column's maximum possible length
> - The character set used for the column, because some character sets    contain multibyte characters

[image]

Comment: I believe then smaller the length, lesser the space even though maxlength is 65535.

Comment: @NavinNagpal:- Yes, I have updated my answer to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL generally, TEXT is a special case. Fields are usually stored on disk in order to facilitate access and indexing but TEXT and BLOBS tend to be stored (and ignored) in a separate block of disk space with only the offset stored in the row.
Therefore, there is no need to allocate the extra space. Updating the value simply results in a single update of an offset pointer within the main table storage area and saving out the current value within the block - there is virtually nothing to be gained performance-wise in reserving enough space for the maximum value.
Almost certainly, the actual value is stored to take up just the required space at any given time. Varchars, on the other hand, were traditionally stored within the actual row and so were allocated the maximum amount of space. This may have changed since their size grew to 16 bits or may not.